# Let qt-creator know, that this is not a c keyword

Tags: c, this, qt-creator

I have a c program that uses this as a keyword to emulate object oriented programming like in c++. Unfortunately qtcreator (version 4.1.0, Xubuntu Linux) cannot deal with it. `this` is recognized as keyword.

It looks like this:

[image: underlining error]

Is there a way to make qtcreator unrecognize the `this` keyword?

Comment: Not sure, but try `#define this` at the very begin.

Comment: This is not a programming question, but a configuration for qt-creator, don't tag it as C.